# It's about time [she came/has come], It's about time [to verb]

Tags: phrase-usage

The scenario is that you have been waiting for your daughter or wife that is visiting a friend of hers. Your son complains about them taking so long.

In this scenario I would say:

> It's about time she came home

But then again this construction attracted my attention, and I would like to know whether it is correct or not.

> It's about time she's come home

**Edit:**
Incidentally: what about this construction: *It's about time [to verb]* as in:

> It's about time to leave now.

Is it plain wrong?

**P.S:**

I think the construction is alright regardless of my example being awkward. I have found this by Robert Feder, The Chicago Sun-Times, 2007 via COCA:

> We did the documentary about four years ago. It 's about time to go
>   back and do a follow-up.

Comment: Is this statement made before or after they get home? As written, "It's about time..." would usually be said after the fact.

Comment: It's said when she had not come home yet

Comment: ...daughter or wife *who*....    *their* taking so long...

Comment: Yes, "it's about time to leave" is fine.  [See COCA.](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=33612600)

Comment: @TimRomano: Actually, “wife ***or*** daughter” is singular, so it should be “*her* taking so long.”

Comment: @TimRomano Are you suggesting that "that" should only be used informally? - I admit that who is more suitable for written English.

Comment: @Scott. Agreed. Haste.

Comment: @Scott Yours makes sense. I got used to theirs because of how often I reference he or she with they.

Comment: _"It's **about time** to leave **now**."_ <== The "about time" and the "now" are clashing with each other. You would normally use one or the other: "It's ***about time*** to leave", or "It's time to leave ***now***".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial instincts were better.  *It's about time she came home.*

It is a subjunctive. But better would be

**Yes, she should be home by now.**

When your wife or daughter finally arrives, very late, *then* you would say:

**It's about time she came home!**

EDIT: You would exclaim the above *only after* wife|daughter had finally gotten home because it means *The person has done what was expected of him or her (in this case, gotten home) but has taken a very long time to do it.*  Another example: diner at a restaurant waiting a very long time for the waiter to come over to his table.  Waiter finally arrives. Diner says curtly:

**It's about time you came over!** or **It's about time you waited on me!**

The *Sun-Times* example *We did the documentary about four years ago. It's about time to go back and do a follow-up.*   has an infinitive "to go" after "it's about time" whereas your sentence has a past-tense "came" (acting in a subjunctive role). The *Sun-Times* scenario is not an analogue for your situation.

The follow-up is due.  Your wife|daughter is *overdue*.

If the documentary producer wanted to convey the idea that the follow up ought really to have been done long before now, that too much time has elapsed, he would say:

**It's about time we *went* back and *did* a follow-up.**

EDIT 2:

And to confuse things even further, *intonation pattern* can change the meaning.

**It's about time she came *home*!**

means she has not yet arrived and is long overdue.

**It's about *time* she came home!**

means she has finally arrived home.

Comment: Look again. The OP asked two questions in one question; the second one ***is*** asking about “it’s about time” + infinitive (“*It’s about time [to verb]*), e.g., “It's about time to leave now.”

Comment: He asked if it was "plain wrong". Not sure what my looking again would change. Then he goes on to justify his own use by referring to that quote.

Comment: @TimRomano I'm sorry I didn't get why would I say that *after* she comes. Would that be sarcastic? If not could you explain it by paraphrasing it in a clearer language? on second thought, do you mean it means just "you're late"?

Comment: @Tim: We’re just having a little problem communicating. I interpreted your “The _Sun-Times_ scenario is not an analogue for your situation.” statement as meaning, “The ‘It’s about time to go back’ example is irrelevant to your question, which is about past tense/subjunctive.” And so I thought that you had maybe overlooked the fact that he had asked a second question (“Is ‘It’s about time to leave now.’ plain wrong?”), and that he was using the _Sun-Times_ quote to answer his own (second) question.

Comment: Ah, plenty of opportunities for miscommunication on a website format.  I will append a note to my answer to clarify.